# Trailing comma setting

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I have few warnings like this upon build:

```
[WRN] C1000: Rhino Parse Warning (Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initializer => somewhere in my code
```

I prefer to have trailing comma, since I don't care about old IEs, and so I don't want to see those warnings and want to disable them.

Is there a way to do this?

I seen some thread about similar question on sencha forums, but can't find it now. It haven't had any accepted or real answer anyway. Something about - look at `ant`, or something like this.